# C# substitute of VB 6 Printer Class

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, vb6-migration

I need a substitute of VB6 Printer Class:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility
```

I checked `System.Drawing.Printing` in C# but not getting direct alternative of Printer object in VB6.

```
Set p = Printer
```

Any link would be more helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A 1:1 translation is often not the best way to approach a translation of VB6 code to VB.NET/C#

Comment: @HelO'Ween I have a legacy very old Visual Basic 6 application. It has a code to print some results with properties like FontSize, Margin etc. I have to rewrite this code in C#. Was thinking if there is a substitute of the class mentioned above, my work would get simple.

Comment: BTW, is there a way to check who marked this question to be Closed and for what reason ?

Comment: @RKh I'm guessing it's being marked as closed as you are "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more " - which is specifically not allowed on SO.

Comment: @Neil Well, if you can't ask for a substitute of a Class Library, it is a weird policy.

Comment: Also "I checked other Printer Classes" is not a great help.  Which *other* classes did you check? You don't want someone spending 10 minutes listing everything you have already rejected.

Comment: @Neil OK. Updating original post.

Comment: `System.Drawing.Printing` looks like the right thing to me.  As @HelO'Ween posted, there will not be a drop in replacement.  I'm guessing that VB6 had some sort of reporting engine, that is not available in .NET. `StandardPrintController.OnStartPrint` basically gives you a `Graphics` object to start writing to.

Comment: Why not just use the VB6 Printer class?

Comment: @BrianMStafford I tried adding in VS solution but I am not getting any option to initiate printer object and declare margin properties.

Comment: @RKh When I compare the Printer properties between VB6 and the compatibility library they are nearly identical.  Neither one has properties for Margin though.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Are you comparing with System.Drawing.Printing ?

Comment: @RKh I was comparing the `VB6 Printer` to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing`.

Comment: Neil's guess as to the close reasons is correct.

Comment: What is wrong with using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility` ?   The whole point of that class seems to be exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: @StayOnTarget I am using C# and added this class reference. I want to know how to create Printer object in C# . In the original post, I mentioned: Set p = Printer, which is in VB

Comment: How to set printer name ? I checked the properties but not getting any property where printer name can be set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to illustrate how to use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility`.  This is nearly identical to VB6 code I have had in production for many years.  It should be noted that DeviceName is read-only even in VB6 so you need to iterate the list of printers looking for a match.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility.VB6;

private void Test()
{
   //get the default printer
   Printer p = new Printer();
   MessageBox.Show(p.DeviceName);

   //print to non-default printer
   p = FindPrinter("some printer name");

   if (p != null)
   {
      p.CurrentX = 500;
      p.CurrentY = 500;
      p.Print("Some text out to specified printer");
      p.EndDoc();
   }
}

private Printer FindPrinter(string DeviceName)
{
   var Printers = new PrinterCollection();

   foreach (Printer p in Printers)
   {
      if (p.DeviceName == DeviceName) return p;
   }

   return null;
}
```